# In bash, is it possible to put several arrays inside quotes and then access them?

Tags: arrays, bash, quotes

I know I can do this:

```
set=("1 2 3" "4 5 6")
for subset in "${set[@]}"
do
for element in $subset
do
echo $element
done
done
```

1 2 3 4 5 6 will be printed sequentially. However, I can **not** do this:

```
  set="(1 2 3) (4 5 6)"
  for subset in $set
  do
  echo ${subset[2]}
  done
```

I want to print 3 6. The reason why I want to do this is that I want to have access to whichever element I want to access during iteration instead of iterating one by one. That's why I try to put arrays inside quotes instead of putting quotes inside a big array. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks,

Comment: As said in the answer below, bash doesn't support multidimensional arrays. If you can rethink your design so as to not require this feature, do so. If you absolutely need multidimensional arrays, use a language that supports them (Perl, Python, etc.)

Comment: `bash` arrays are not intended for building complicated data structures; they are a second level of quoting for storing command line arguments which themselves must be quoted. Example: `a=("foo bar" "1 2 3"); some_command "${a[@]}"`, which provides exactly two arguments to `some_command`: `foo bar` and `1 2 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think bash supports multi-dimentional arrays, which sounds like what you're looking for. You can simulate it with a little help from bash itself like so:

```
x=()
x+=("1,2,3")
x+=("4,5,6")

for val in ${x[@]}; do
    subset=($(echo $val | tr ',' ' '))
    echo ${subset[2]}
done
```