# Bash - multi indexed arrays [$i][$i]

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

i have a script which get datas from a file, but some parameters have more values than just one.

How can i make that my bash script can read as example:

```
user[3][1]=test1
user[3][2]=test2
```

Actually i make:

```
for i in $(seq ${#lala[@]}); do
${user[$i]}
done
```

which works. I have try it with ${user[$i][$i]} and seq ${#lala[@][@]}) but i cant get it running.

The script must then work with just [$i] and [$i][$i].

Can please somebody help me out, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're using wrong language/script, since BASH doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays. Having said that you can store a delimited text in each element of array that you can further break into array inside a loop.

Comment: So you mean user[3]=test1,test2?

Do you maybe have a code example how can i use it in a script to read all values one after one?

Comment: If you can provide some sample data in your question on what your input is then I can sure make a script for you.

Comment: I saw your script but unable to understand where you want 2D array.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919652/in-bash-is-it-possible-to-put-several-arrays-inside-quotes-and-then-access-them/19919978#19919978

Comment: ${hdd[$i]} must be 2d array

Comment: @user2933212: See linked example from MannyD